# What do you consider a well received question?

Tags: support, badges, questions, votes, up-votes

How many positive arrows does a question need to be considered a well received question?

Comment: In what context? It sounds like you've seen "well received" used somewhere, in a badge description maybe?

Comment: @ terdon. You are correct. In the badge despriptions.

Answer (score 5):

I believe for the badges (Curious, Inquisitive and Socratic), a "well-received question" means that *the question itself* has a positive score, i.e. 1 or more. This can be 2 positives and 1 negative vote, it's still well received in total.

Looking at your question history, this would mean you have 3 out of 5 well-received questions for the Curious badge (for the main site).